# Conductor electric field vs insulator electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Suppose I have a piece of wood and a piece of copper wire. I apply **100V** to both of the material, my question is both is going to produce electric field inside the material, but which field is stronger?

**1.** Are electric field strength depend on the type(conductor/insulator) of material they are applied to?

**2.** Also is the field strength uniform everywhere in the material when a fixed voltage is applied to it?

Comment: Wood is a living organism, so it is not a simple material but a composite one. The breakdown voltage cannot be precise and conductivity can also be ionic. A field can be shielded, less for a collective motion.

Comment: The answers (especially to #2) depend on what kind of shape the objects have (A cube? A long "wire"? A thin sheet?), and how you are applying the voltage (is it applied through wires connected to two points on the object, or via wide plates on two surfaces like a capacitor?).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the E-field would be the same. But because of the low resistance of copper, some point of the circuit would break due to the high current and dissipated power.  If the piece of wire was thick enough, the wiring in the source would fail.

If the piece of wood is reasonably homogeneous, the E-field is constant along it, as along the copper piece.

Comment: No. Inside a metal there will be no E field in this electrostatic case. Only the insulator can have some E field inside.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent if there is no E field in this case then how electrons are being pushed?

Comment: @Sayan this is the most basic of electrostatics. There will only be E field outside conductors. The electrons have already been pushed.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent there is no electric field if the ohmic resistance is zero. For a real copper wire there is an Electric field.